# Определить город по его неверному или частичному названию?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Например, чтобы по "мск" или "масква" мне вернуло "Москва", по "питер" вернуло Санкт-Петербург и т.д.
Пока у меня почти получилось это сделать через 2 запроса - сначала прямое геокодирование на то, что ввел пользователь, затем обратное чтобы по координатам поучить город.
Но проблема в том, что этот механизм то работает, то нет. Потому что Яндекс как-то по разному определяет и координаты и месту и место по координатам.
Вообще, использование двух запросов, это единственный вариант?

Comment: https://dadata.ru/suggestions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) В **JavaScript API** можно использовать поисковые подсказки, вот описание и пример в песочнице: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/suggest-docpage/

```
ymaps.suggest('мск')
.then(function (items) {
    // items - массив поисковых подсказок.
    console.log(items);
});
```

Может быть полезным параметр boundedBy.

Если строка для поиска вводится пользователем, можно использовать панель с поисковыми подсказками. Вот пример в песочнице: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/suggest

2) Также можно использовать **API Поиска по организациям** (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/ ).

В документации (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/doc/examples/geosearch_examples-docpage/ ) есть пример запроса с орфографической ошибкой «Масква». Ответ будет содержать исправленный вариант:
[https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=Масква&type=geo&lang=ru_RU&apikey=](https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0&type=geo&lang=ru_RU&apikey=)

На запросы "мск" и "питер" API также возвращает исправленный ответ.

Comment: Это не совсем то. Во-первых, мне не надо чтобы что-то типа подсказок отображалось. Во-вторых, если человек ввел "мск" и нажал кнопку "искать", то я не вижу как мне используя подсказки и не показывая их, получить слово "Москва" - то есть тот город, который скорее всего подходит по поисковый запрос.

Comment: Код "ymaps.suggest('мск').then(function (items)" в моем примере не отображает подсказки - в массиве items при успешном поиске будут возвращены подходящие объекты-топонимы.

Comment: дополнил ответ, добавил API Поиска по организациям

Comment: Спасибо, большое за ответ! Вы помогли.

Comment: Но к сожалению этот способ работает не до конца. На слово "масква" он находит "Масква-Лейк", что в Канаде. Хотя если написать "масква" в Яндекс картах, то там найдет верно.